# Bash integer operation on string extracted from Python script

Tags: python, bash

I have a bash script which extracts a variable (an integer) calculated in a Python script. I then try to do an arithmetic operation on this variable, but Bash seems to have trouble with this.

Python script:

```
import sys
foo = 278736 # This number is obtained by reading a file using this Python script
print(foo)
sys.exit(0)
```

Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
var=`python python_script.py`
var2=$((var/100))             # Line which causes the problem
```

This produces this error:

```
-bash: 278736: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "278736")
```

It seems that somehow, bash doesn't know how to convert the string "278736", extracted from the Python script, to an integer.  If I do an arithmetic operation with a normal Bash variable, it works fine:

```
var_test=278736
var2=$((var_test/100))             # Works fine
```

I have searched, but can't find anybody who has asked the same question.  Does anyone know how to make this work?

Comment: Works for me with python 2.7 and python 3.6 on bash 3.2 and bash 4-4.  By the way, nothing to do with your issue, but `$( )` is preferred over the obsolete \`backticks\`

Comment: This works fine for me `var=$(python -c "print(278736)"); var2=$((var/100)); echo "$var2"`. BTW, you don't need that `sys.exit(0)`, the Python interpreter normally returns 0 to the OS without needing an explicit `exit` call.

Comment: I can reproduce exactly your error message by inserting another `print(foo)` in the python script *before* the existing one.  I think you could get this with any other non-whitespace `print()` before the one you need. Check your whole python code for other `print()` statements.